# How to align the bar in stack chart in d3 js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

HI as i'm trying to align the horizontal stacked bar chart using d3.js.
Here i'm using `d3.stack()` method to generate the stacked bar. This works fine with set of data

```
dataset = [{
  "goodRating": 12,
  "avgRating": 12,
  "badRating": 12,
}]
```

But when im trying to change the data to

```
dataset = [{
  "goodRating": 2344412,
  "avgRating": 23234434,
  "badRating": 443333,
}]
```

This works but alignment doesn't fit into the chart width. 
As i want to fit the bar chart inside the svg to 100%. Please check my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fekkyDev/hquvz2m3/4/) 
Can please suggest me what i have missed. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `width` and `x` of `rect` as percentage

```
attr('width', function(d) {
   return (d[1] - d[0]) + '%';
})
.attr('x', function(d) {
    return d[0] + '%';
})
```

**Demo**

https://jsfiddle.net/aswinkumar863/7bnmr9cd/

Comment: can you please change the dataset to  var dataset2 = [{
      "goodRating": 23232122,
      "avgRating": 2323132122,
      "badRating": 12321313,
      
    }];